# TSNE from **sklearn** with **mahalanobis** metric

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

With TSNE from **sklearn** with **mahalanobis** metric I am getting following error

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE      
tsne = TSNE( verbose=1, perplexity=40, n_iter=250,learning_rate=50, random_state=0,metric='mahalanobis')
pt=data.sample(frac=0.1).values
tsne_results = tsne.fit_transform(pt)
```

**`ValueError: Must provide either V or VI for Mahalanobis distance`**

How to provide an method_parameters for the Mahalanobis distance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed there is no option to define the metric_params as in the other cases. For example other pairwise distance based classes provide a `metric_params` parameter to pass additional params to the distance function. Like

- [KNeighborsClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html)
- [NearestNeighbors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html)

have this:

```
metric_params : dict, optional (default = None)

    Additional keyword arguments for the metric function.
```

This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34650347/3374996) shows how to use this param.

But TSNE has no way to send the additional parameters. So for now, you need to extend the class and over-ride the `__init__()` to send the parameters and then [`_fit()` method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py#L615) to actually use them.

We can do this:

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.externals.six import string_types
from sklearn.utils import check_array, check_random_state
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
from sklearn.manifold.t_sne import _joint_probabilities, _joint_probabilities_nn
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

class MyTSNE(TSNE):
    def __init__(self, n_components=2, perplexity=30.0,
                 early_exaggeration=12.0, learning_rate=200.0, n_iter=1000,
                 n_iter_without_progress=300, min_grad_norm=1e-7,
                 metric="euclidean", metric_params=None, #<=ADDED
                 init="random", verbose=0,
                 random_state=None, method='barnes_hut', angle=0.5):
        self.n_components = n_components
        self.perplexity = perplexity
        self.early_exaggeration = early_exaggeration
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.n_iter_without_progress = n_iter_without_progress
        self.min_grad_norm = min_grad_norm
        self.metric = metric
        self.metric_params = metric_params  #<=ADDED
        self.init = init
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.method = method
        self.angle = angle

    def _fit(self, X, skip_num_points=0):
        if self.method not in ['barnes_hut', 'exact']:
            raise ValueError("'method' must be 'barnes_hut' or 'exact'")
        if self.angle < 0.0 or self.angle > 1.0:
            raise ValueError("'angle' must be between 0.0 - 1.0")
        if self.metric == "precomputed":
            if isinstance(self.init, string_types) and self.init == 'pca':
                raise ValueError("The parameter init=\"pca\" cannot be "
                                 "used with metric=\"precomputed\".")
            if X.shape[0] != X.shape[1]:
                raise ValueError("X should be a square distance matrix")
            if np.any(X < 0):
                raise ValueError("All distances should be positive, the "
                                 "precomputed distances given as X is not "
                                 "correct")
        if self.method == 'barnes_hut' and sp.issparse(X):
            raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense '
                            'data is required for method="barnes_hut". Use '
                            'X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array if '
                            'the array is small enough for it to fit in '
                            'memory. Otherwise consider dimensionality '
                            'reduction techniques (e.g. TruncatedSVD)')
        else:
            X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'],
                            dtype=[np.float32, np.float64])
        if self.method == 'barnes_hut' and self.n_components > 3:
            raise ValueError("'n_components' should be inferior to 4 for the "
                             "barnes_hut algorithm as it relies on "
                             "quad-tree or oct-tree.")
        random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)

        if self.early_exaggeration < 1.0:
            raise ValueError("early_exaggeration must be at least 1, but is {}"
                             .format(self.early_exaggeration))

        if self.n_iter < 250:
            raise ValueError("n_iter should be at least 250")

        n_samples = X.shape[0]

        neighbors_nn = None
        if self.method == "exact":
            if self.metric == "precomputed":
                distances = X
            else:
                if self.verbose:
                    print("[t-SNE] Computing pairwise distances...")

                if self.metric == "euclidean":
                    distances = pairwise_distances(X, metric=self.metric,
                                                   squared=True,
                                                   **self.metric_params) #<=ADDED
                else:
                    distances = pairwise_distances(X, metric=self.metric,
                                                   **self.metric_params) #<=ADDED

                if np.any(distances < 0):
                    raise ValueError("All distances should be positive, the "
                                     "metric given is not correct")

            P = _joint_probabilities(distances, self.perplexity, self.verbose)
            assert np.all(np.isfinite(P)), "All probabilities should be finite"
            assert np.all(P >= 0), "All probabilities should be non-negative"
            assert np.all(P <= 1), ("All probabilities should be less "
                                    "or then equal to one")

        else:
            k = min(n_samples - 1, int(3. * self.perplexity + 1))

            if self.verbose:
                print("[t-SNE] Computing {} nearest neighbors...".format(k))

            knn = NearestNeighbors(algorithm='auto', n_neighbors=k,
                                   metric=self.metric, 
                                   metric_params = self.metric_params) #<=ADDED
            t0 = time()
            knn.fit(X)
            duration = time() - t0
            if self.verbose:
                print("[t-SNE] Indexed {} samples in {:.3f}s...".format(
                    n_samples, duration))

            t0 = time()
            distances_nn, neighbors_nn = knn.kneighbors(
                None, n_neighbors=k)
            duration = time() - t0
            if self.verbose:
                print("[t-SNE] Computed neighbors for {} samples in {:.3f}s..."
                      .format(n_samples, duration))

            del knn

            if self.metric == "euclidean":
                distances_nn **= 2

            P = _joint_probabilities_nn(distances_nn, neighbors_nn,
                                        self.perplexity, self.verbose)

        if isinstance(self.init, np.ndarray):
            X_embedded = self.init
        elif self.init == 'pca':
            pca = PCA(n_components=self.n_components, svd_solver='randomized',
                      random_state=random_state)
            X_embedded = pca.fit_transform(X).astype(np.float32, copy=False)
        elif self.init == 'random':
            X_embedded = 1e-4 * random_state.randn(
                n_samples, self.n_components).astype(np.float32)
        else:
            raise ValueError("'init' must be 'pca', 'random', or "
                             "a numpy array")

        degrees_of_freedom = max(self.n_components - 1.0, 1)

        return self._tsne(P, degrees_of_freedom, n_samples,
                          X_embedded=X_embedded,
                          neighbors=neighbors_nn,
                          skip_num_points=skip_num_points)
```

I have marked (#<=ADDED) on the changes. Now try using this class instead of TSNE like this:

```
tsne = MyTSNE(verbose=1,perplexity=40,n_iter=250,learning_rate=50, random_state=0,
              metric='mahalanobis', metric_params={'V': np.cov(X)})

pt=data.sample(frac=0.1).values
tsne_results = tsne.fit_transform(pt)
```

**Note**:
Other classes that I mentioned on the top check the `metric_params` for valid params, but I have not done that, so make sure you pass correct parameters in it, else it will give errors.

You should post the issue on [scikit-learn issues page on github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues)

Comment: Bravo!!! just minor comment change the line to  metric=self.metric, metric_params=self.metric_params) #<=ADDED

Comment: @Arman Aah, yes. I copy-pasted that from above usage of `pairwise_distances` where the params are keyword arguments. I forgot the `NearestNeighbors` require dict, not `kwargs`. Thanks. Changed

Comment: @Arman Yes, I saw and commented some info about the root cause of issue.